# Visual studio code color theme not taking

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, color-scheme

I am using VsCode version 1.30.1.

I have [forked a color theme on github](https://github.com/safield/comfortable-color-theme), and can't get it to work.

I cloned the repo into my .vscode/extensions folder.

The color theme shows up when I go to color theme selector is VsCode.

But when I set the color theme, it does not change, even after a reboot.

Is there a way I could get a verbose log from the application when it tries to load the plugin?

Comment: There are comments in your `.json` files, you can not have comments in a `.json`
You also have a missing `,` on line 20 of `plastic-theme.json`

Comment: Yes. I was able to figure out how to get the errors by toggling developer mode, to get the same conclusion as you. If you consolidate our two comments into an answer, you will get the bounty :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can open a developer window by going to `Help` > `Toggle Developer Tools` to get more visibility of the errors from load attempts. Also if you open the files in VS code the syntax highlighting will also show the errors in the files in your case.

The specific errors are comments in your `.json` files, you can not have comments in a `.json` and a missing `,` on line 20 of plastic-theme.json

Image for reference on accessing developer tools.
[image]